# iOS, UIPickerView with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UIPickerView` inside of a view controller that implements `-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view`

I have used `UITableViewCell` to make use of the `accessoryType`, `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`. I'm having trouble wording the process of the overall view controller so i will use code:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;
    if( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        if([[[self.currentData objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"uuid"] isEqualToString:self.currentProfile] || [[[self.currentData objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"description"] isEqualToString:self.currentSelectedRow]){
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
                cell.tag = 10;
                self.Switch.on = TRUE;
        }
        [cell setBounds: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width -20 , 44)];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.currentData objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"description"];
    return cell;
}
```

A `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the `UIPickerView` calls this:

```
-(void)pickerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect frame = self.pick.frame;
    CGRect selectFrame = CGRectInset(frame, 0.0, self.pick.bounds.size.height * 0.85 / 2.0);
    //if the tap gesture is onto of the picker view, & the enabled switch is on
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(selectFrame, touchPoint) && self.Switch.on){
        //clear all cells of check mark
        for(int i = 0; i < [self.pick numberOfRowsInComponent:0]; i++){
            UITableViewCell *tmpCell = (UITableViewCell *) [self.pick viewForRow:i forComponent:0];
            tmpCell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        [self.pick reloadAllComponents];

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.pick viewForRow:[self.pick selectedRowInComponent:0] forComponent:0];
        self.currentSelectedRow = cell.textLabel.text;
        if(cell.tag == 10){
            //user tapped on already ticked cell, wishes to untick
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.tag = 0;
            self.currentSelectedRow = nil;
        } else{
            //user has selected un-ticked row, wishes to tick
            //clear all cells of tags
            for(int i = 0; i < [self.pick numberOfRowsInComponent:0]; i++){
                UITableViewCell *tmpCell = (UITableViewCell *) [self.pick viewForRow:i forComponent:0];
                tmpCell.tag = 0;
            }
            //assign new ticked cell & update currentProfile
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            cell.tag = 10;
            self.currentProfile = [[self.currentData objectAtIndex:[self.pick selectedRowInComponent:0]] valueForKey:@"uuid"];
        }
    } 
    //[self.pick reloadAllComponents];  <-- this is a key part. take note.
}
```

**Heres the issue:**
The overall aim of this is that the user can have no rows ticked, or one row ticked at any one time. If the view controller loads & the current profile is set, i.e an representation of existing data. then relating row is ticked.

Simple. However...

The `[self.pick reloadAllComponents]` at the bottom of the pickerTapped: function, when uncommented out, results in the picker view able to handle non, or only 1 row ticked. but unable to handle row deselect/untick.

When the same line is commented the picker is able to handle non selected rows, but behaves oddly with single selected row. i can select & deselect a row fine, however when i select a different row, the accessoryType is updated for the cell in the 'selection box' part of the picker view (two lines in the middle), but when i scroll on the picker, the cell in question displays as if the accessory has not been updated. Just to clarify, when i scroll the cell back into the 'selection box' it appears fine as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Awkwardly managed to resolve this shortly after posting.

Sods law & all that

On `pickerTapped:`, where `currentSelectedRow = nil`, `self.currentProfile` should also be set to nil. The `reloadAllComponents` should be uncommeted